# Is there a programming language to improve environmental problems?

Tags: programming-languages, article

I am a student in a university, and I'm studying and making the programming language with delimited continuations. I want to use this study to improve environmental problems. Here, The word "environmental" means nature of the Earth. I searched articles about programming languages and environmental problems. I found articles about software or hardware to improve environmental problems. However I could not find articles about programming languages to improve environmental problems.

I heard that the programming language which is useful to make efficient algorithms is good to improve environmental problems. So, I think there are some cases that the programming language is good to improve environmental problems. However, as I wrote above, I could not find such case. Do you know studies or articles about programming languages to improve environmental problems?

Comment: Never heard of this before. There is always a solution based on a a language, and the solution should focus on environmental problems to solve them. I don't get you at all!

Comment: Less CPU cycles doesn't improve environment problems... Not unless your application runs a photosynthesis machine like structure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have watched an interview with Bjarne Stroustrup where he claims C++ has contributed against global warming, since the language is so efficient and fast compared to some others I won't name, since I really hate language wars anyway.

I don't know if that answers your question. Nice one, though.

[How C++ Combats Global Warming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBWeO2HYEc0)

Comment: I will watch the link. Thank you very much!

Comment: Np. You can contact these people also. https://www.vu.nl/en/programmes/international-masters/programmes/c-d/computer-science-software-engineering-green-it/contact/index.aspx

Comment: The time required to debug a C++ program of moderate complexity means burning lots of CPU cycles elsewhere, and heating/cooling the compartment where the programmers debugging that mess work, and providing light, powering a microware owen and the coffee-machine also counts. So please... such BS claims are very easily refuted, you see :-)

Comment: These are not my claims. You may want to refer to bs [at] cs.tamu.edu.

Comment: besides, you can watch this. All of it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nesCaocNjtQ

Answer (score 0):

I used quite some modelling within hydrology, the research of water. For this I used Matlab , SMS, tuflow and Mike Zero - to model rivers, progression of groundwater flow / intrusion of pumping, etc. Hope that helps!